# Remap a key to Ctrl and make it behave like Ctrl during text editing

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I bought a fancy-looking mechanical keyboard in Korea. In general, it works really well except for one thing - even though it has <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys on its right side, these keys do not generate the same codes as a "regular" keyboard.

Long story short, Right <kbd>Alt</kbd> is the Hangul key (changes between Latin and Korean letters) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is Hanja (converts between Hangul and "old" Korean characters). I wanted to use multiple layouts - Korean and my local one (Polish) and keep the best of both worlds - that means making Right <kbd>Alt</kbd> emit the keycode for <kbd>Alt</kbd> while typing Polish and for Hangul while typing in Korean.

Korean worked out of the box (since the keycodes are correct there), but Polish needed tweaks. I changed the layout (`/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pl`) by adding the following lines in the active `xkb_symbols` section:

```
key <HNGL>  { [ ISO_Level3_Shift ] };
key <HJCV>  { [ Control_R ] };
```

And I have commented out the lines related to `HNGL` and `HJCV` in the "inet" layout, since these were overwriting my changes.

After these changes I got <kbd>Alt</kbd> working perfectly, but there was still a problem with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key not working correctly. In general it works, but when editing text, I should be able to e.g. delete one word by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> combination and I'm unable to do so.

I have executed `xset -r 131` in order to disable key repeating for this <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/Hanja key but it still doesn't work like a real <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

Here's the `xev` output of remapped `Hanja`:

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 49086462, (88,89), root:(3928,141),
state 0x10, keycode 131 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 105
XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

And here's a regular <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (from other keyboard):

```
KeyPress event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 49144922, (616,377), root:(4456,429),
state 0x10, keycode 105 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Is there anything I can change to make my system treat that key as a full-blown <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning a key to another is unique when the key is a modifier. 
 This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/391968) has a good explanation:

> The action, when it is a modifier action such as this, changes the current modifier state, which (simply put) is a set of flags recorded in the operating system that record what modifiers are currently "on". [This record] influences what action further keypresses map to.

And so when you are trying to map your key, it is being mapped as a regular key and losing information which specifies how it behaves when multiple keys are pressed.

To demonstrate, run `xmodmap`. Note that there are two default keys (Control_L and Control_R) mapped to the control modifier. If you run `xmodmap -e 'keycode 131 = Control_L'`  and then `xmodmap`, the control modifier should still have two keys, so your key isn't being recognized as a modifier.

To map as a modifier:

Clear the modifier key `control`

```
xmodmap -e 'clear control'
```

Add the keycode for the Hanja key

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 131 = Control_L'
```

Lastly, add back the default modifiers:

```
xmodmap -e 'add control = Control_L'
xmodmap -e 'add control = Control_R'
```

Now, if you were to run xmodmap again, you will notice a new key has been added for the modifier control, and it should work correctly now.

[Here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xmodmap#Activating_the_custom_table) is a link to official Arch Linux instructions on reassigning modifiers to keys on your keyboard.

**edit:**

for persistent changes, add to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pl`:

```
key <HJCV> { [ Control_L ] };

modifier_map Control { Control_L, Control_R, <HJCV> };
```

Comment: That indeed works! Just one follow up - chaning the keyboard layout resets the xmodmap settings - is there any way I can run a script after layout change or put these into xkb layout? All the instructions I have found assume that I'll use just one layout.

Comment: Yes I see, adding `key <HJCV> {   [ Control_L ]   };` and `modifier_map Control  { Control_L, Control_R, <HJCV> };` to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pl` and recaching/rebooting should fix this.