# Trigger Ctrl+key keycode or Hiragana to Control

Tags: japanese, keycodes

I have a JIS keyboard with Katana & Hiragana keys I am trying to bind Control keys.

I tried editing the following file [JIS Keyboard Layout Keyboard Characters](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071801/jis-keyboard-layout-keyboard-characters) but it fails to change the keyboard keys.

Is there a way to bind keys using keycode for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, etc...  I need Hiragana to me mapped to control essentially but it doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 0):

For CUI:

There are some handy packages to manipulate each key and mouse button.
For the packages`xmodmap` `xbindkeys` `xdotool` and `xte` are popular.

`sudo apt install x11-xserver-utils`
`sudo apt install xbindkeys`

Use `xev` and press the Hiragana/Katanaka key and you get the code.

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0xe5, subw 0x0, time 3469373, (-29,-117), root:(36,405),
    state 0x0, keycode 101 (keysym 0xff27, Hiragana_Katakana), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0xe5, subw 0x0, time 3469469, (-29,-117), root:(36,405),
    state 0x0, keycode 101 (keysym 0xff27, Hiragana_Katakana), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Alternatively, you can use `xbindkeys -mk` to get the keycode and numbers.

```
$ xbindkeys -mk
Press combination of keys or/and click under the window.
You can use one of the two lines after "NoCommand"
in $HOME/.xbindkeysrc to bind a key.

--- Press "q" to stop. ---
"(Scheme function)"
    m:0x0 + c:101
    Hiragana_Katakana
```

*I do know know the codes are the same as your IBM keyboard layout.* **You should check on your own keyboard. The numbers may be different.**

Now then, edit `~/.xbindkeysrc` add lines below.  (if there's no such file `xbindkeys --defaults > $HOME/.xbindkeysrc` to create one.

```
"xdotool key ctrl+l"
 m:0x0 + c:101 + release
```

Save this file and
`pkill -f xbindkeys && xbindkeys`
execute this command to apply changes.

---

For GUI

Open System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts

[image: Shortcuts Window]
[image: Control+L]

This one takes only a minute.

Comment: does CTRL and NOT CTRL+L work?

Comment: I tested the second option and it definitely does not work not sure about the first.

Comment: Tested  on gedit and open file window, Ctrl+L to put file path. You need to install `xdotool` first. And in case of Hiragana_Katakana key is reserved by system (does two functions at once) you should disable one. I will edit this answer and add how.

Comment: I have the Hiragana key bound to the Left Control on Windows.  It appears this is not possible on linux I have tried just saying just about everything.

Comment: Do you want to set Hiragana_Katakana key to control key?  Then you need to do more about xmodmap. Original question I understand you want to put the combination of Control + L, not the Left control. Well, I will rewrite my answer.

Comment: I have tried xmodmap and unfortunately it doesn't seem to respect the remapping.

Comment: I realized that is the duplicate of this answer. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036521/remap-a-key-to-ctrl-and-make-it-behave-like-ctrl-during-text-editing/1039625#1039625

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as a partial answer because swapping Hiragana with control seems to be impossible.  What you can do is bind Hiragana to Mode_Switch and use the XF86Paste and XF86Copy, redo, undo, etc...

[image]