# Changing NumPad keycodes to non-NumPad countertypes?

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I have an external keyboard to my laptop which has a NumPad. I want to be able to use both the external keyboard and the built-in keyboard in the same way. However, because the keycodes for the NumPad's Home, End, PgUp, PgDn, etc. are different from those of the keys devoted solely to those functions on the laptop keyboard, I can't make keyboard shortcuts that work for both keyboards. For example, Super+PgDn for moving a workspace down is different from Super+PgDn (NumPad), so I have to choose one or the other in assigning my shortcuts. I still want to be able to use the numbers on the NumPad with NumLock turned on, but I haven't been able to make this work. I tried making changes through `xmodmap` by turning this line of the map:

```
keycode  81 = KP_Prior KP_9 KP_Prior KP_9
```

into this:

```
keycode  81 = Prior 9 Prior 9
```

but then I couldn't use my numbers on the NumPad anymore when NumLock was turned on.

Any suggestions for things I could try? Is what I want even possible, or should I just accept my defeat and buy a new external keyboard? I sadly wasn't able to find anyone with the same problem as me anywhere.

(Another, related, problem: Shift+Home (NumPad) for some reason becomes Shift+7 (NumPad) through this external keyboard; Shift acts basically like a Num Lock, which I don't want either. I'd like to be able to use Shift+Home as a keyboard shortcut, for example.)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, how about `keycode  81 = Prior KP_9 Prior KP_9` does this work? Best to check by `xev` what do you get keycode of your external keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! This gives the following when I press the keys on the NumPad: (PgUp : `Prior`), (9: `KP_9`), (Shift + PgUp: `Shift_L` `KP_9`), (Shift + 9: `Shift_L` `Prior`). I'd like those last two things to be switched, if possible (so pressing shift in combination with a NumPad key doesn't change its meaning). Which parts in my `xmodmap` should I swap?

Comment: `xmodmap` only do one key for a certain keycode, you can't do it with the combination. However `xdotool` or `xte` will do. Register the shortcut Shift+PgUp on the SystemSettings > Keyboard, it's simple. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232137/trigger-ctrlkey-keycode-or-hiragana-to-control/1232693#1232693